# Python importing inside a project with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, importerror

I am trying to add some unit tests to a project, but the imports inside the project are not working.

The project structure is as follows:

```
root
| src
| | __init__.py
| | bsp.py
| | helpers.py
| test
| | __init__.py
| | test_helpers.py
```

both **init**.py are empty.
bsp.py looks as follows:

```
class BSP:
    # some class stuff
```

helpers.py looks as follows:

```
from bsp import BSP

def func(x: BSP) -> BSP:
    return x
```

Finally test_helpers.py looks as follows:

```
from src.helpers import func
from src.bsp import BSP
from unittest import TestCase

class TestFunc(TestCase):
    def test_func(self):
        x = BSP()
        assert func(x) == x
```

When I run `pytest` from root, importing does not work:

```
File "...\\root\\tests\\test_helpers.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from src.helpers import func
File "...\\root\\src\\helpers.py", line 1, in \<module\>  
from bsp import BSP
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bsp'
```

However running the function from src does work.

I am probably doing something dumb, but I have been looking for a while and am unsure what I am doing wrong :sweat_smile:

I have already tried:

- Adding . in front of bsp in `from bsp import BSP` in src/helpers.py; However now imports in the src are broken (e.g. src/main.py executes func from helper, raises an import error if a . is added)
- Tried using `pytest`, `py -m pytest`, `unittest`, `py -m unittest`
- Tried adding **init**.py in root, and adding/removing from src/test

Comment: Have you tried `from .bsp import BSP`? Also `from ./bsp import BSP`

Comment: Yes, but then running the function from inside the package fails:
say we have root/src/main.py with:
```
from helpers import func
func(bsp)
```
Then with `from .bsp import BSP` fails. Pytest then does work though:

edit: ./ does not work at all

Comment: Your import paths should never have `src` in them, and `src` shouldn't have an `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently. If you are using PyCharm, this might do the trick.
Setting the 'sources root' folder.

1. Right-click your src folder.
2. Go to the last option "Mark directory as".
3. Select 'Sources Root'.

[Setting your sources root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foeaK.png)

Hope this helps.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, this did unfortunately not help

Comment: Since you do not seem to have conflicting file names, can you try just importing it this way 'from bsp import BSP'? IDEs are smart enough to fetch it without the 'src.' prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Adding;

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

to `src/\_\_init\_\_.py` makes it work for both running the function inside the package, and from pytest. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375740/23736554).

Comment: But it's also a terrible, bad idea if you're ever considering distributing your package or making it reusable. You should make your package correctly installable (since you're using an `src` layout), then install it as editable, and pytest would find it fine. I suggest https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/ for packaging.